# Приложение работало в симуляторе, но при проверке инспекторами апстор оно не запускается - лишь чёрный экран

Tags: ios, swift, appstore

Мы недавно выпустили обновление нашего приложения в аппсторе, но его вернули с вот таким текстом:

```
Guideline 2.1 - Performance - App Completeness


We discovered one or more bugs in your app when reviewed on iPad and iPhone running iOS 10.3.2 on Wi-Fi connected to an IPv6 network.

Specifically, the app content fails to load after we launch. The app displays black screen indefinitely. 

Please see attached screenshots for details.

Next Steps

To resolve this issue, please run your app on a device to identify any issues, then revise and resubmit your app for review.

If we misunderstood the intended behavior of your app, please reply to this message in Resolution Center to provide information on how these features were intended to work.

For new apps, uninstall all previous versions of your app from a device, then install and follow the steps to reproduce the issue. For updates, install the new version as an update to the previous version, then follow the steps to reproduce the issue.

Resources

For information about testing your app and preparing it for review, please see Technical Note TN2431: App Testing Guide. 

For a networking overview, please review About Networking. For a more specific overview of App Review’s IPv6 requirements, please review the IPv6 and App Review discussion on the Apple Developer Forum.
```

Хотя перед отправкой на симуляторе оно нормально работало. Я даже не знаю откуда начать копать. Может это единичный сбой и если ещё раз отправить на проверку то всё прокатит?

UPDT:

Перед этим была странная проблема. Вдруг ни с того ни с сего в консоли стали писаться бесконечно строки (не помню точно, что-то там про смену правил cookie с 0 на 2 или как-то так). Я где-то вычитал совет что надо очистить поле Main Interface в настройках. Не знаю совпадение ли (скорее всего) но это помогло. И приложение успешно работало. Но видимо в этом может быть причина чёрного экрана.

Comment: Как задан у Вас initial view controller? Просто в storyboard или в AppDelegate прописываете?

Comment: Возможно в этом и проблема, попробуйте почистить симулятор и установить приложение на чистую. Так же попробуйте запустить его на девайсе.

Comment: @VAndrJ да в сториборде инишел контроллер.

Comment: @VitaliEller видимо эта ситуация возникла из-за того, что в симуляторе видимо я проверил на горячую, и там видимо не применилась ещё эта настройка, потому и работало всё перед отправкой в стор. А уже потом, после возврата, я заново запустил на симуляторе, и уже не работало и после запуска ланч скрина чёрный экран. Но после того как я в настройках поставил Main.storyboard, как главный интерфейс, то всё заработало. Сейчас приложение на проверке в сторе. Надеюсь в этот раз прокатит.

Comment: Тогда действительно проблема в этом. Его стоит очищать только если указываете программно в AppDelegate.

Comment: @VAndrJ теперь буду знать) Я просто когда столкнулся с той проблемой, когда в лог выводились непонятные бесконечные сообщения, то надо было срочно найти какое-то решение, ну и попробовал первый попавшийся совет из гугла, а оказалось напортачил ещё больше))

Comment: На будущее - перед отправкой на проверку тестируйте через TestFlight. Это практически то же самое что видят проверяющие.

Comment: @IvanKramarchuk надо будет попробовать. Спасибо.